# how to convert query sentences to DB::raw eloquent laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5

```
SELECT u.*,(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT id,author_id FROM posts p
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, author_id FROM updates up
) total_table WHERE author_id = u.id) as total_post FROM users u ORDER BY total_post
```

i have query line want to DB::raw. Can you help me??? many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `raw query` like:

```
DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT u.*,(
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT id,author_id FROM posts p
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, author_id FROM updates up
) total_table WHERE author_id = u.id) as total_post FROM users u ORDER BY total_post'));
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this by using `DB::satement`

```
$query='SELECT u.*,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT id,author_id FROM posts p
UNION ALL
SELECT id, author_id FROM updates up) total_table WHERE author_id = u.id) as total_post FROM users u ORDER BY total_post';
$data=DB::statement($query);
```

Like this.